# OS X Numbers: How to use a spreadsheet value as a label

Tags: numbers

I have a basic spreadsheet chart, which also includes a single labeled cell (set as a slider) that is used as a constant multiplier.   (In this case, it is used to vary the number of workdays.)

I would like to use that value in the title of the chart: I.e.

"Salaries normalized to {NormDays} schooldays"

If there is no direct way, in the alternative what is the best way to display it floating on the chart on the chart in numeric form, possible with a label.... i.e.:   Workdays: {NormDays}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, chart titles and labels (and text boxes) can't contain formulae.  So I think this isn't possible in the ways that you suggest.

An alternative is to place a single-cell table on top of the chart, with the cell containing a formula like `= "Salaries normalised to " & B1 & " school days"`.

[image: Single-cell table table on top of chart]

I'm using Numbers '09... hopefully this still works in later versions...